# How to querySelect Lit-Element that is within another Lit-Element

Tags: jquery, polymer, web-frontend, polymer-3.x, lit-element

Parent element(x-app tag) displaying child1(x-counter),child2(child2-app) elements and whenever there is any change in child1, I would like to update it to child2 as well. So, in the parent I am trying to get the property of child 2 using querySelect but I am getting null value.

ready(){
    super.ready();

```
document.querySelector('x-counter').addEventListener('valueChange',function(e){
  this.b = e.detail;

  const val = document.querySelector('x-app');
  console.log(val.querySelector('child2-app');
  val.a = this.b;


});
```

}

static get template(){

```
return html`
  <x-counter></x-counter>
<child2-app></child2-app>

`;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here parent `x-app` element property share example:

```
static get template(){

return html`
  <x-counter  my-property = "{{myProperty}}" ></x-counter>
  <child2-app  my-property = "{{myProperty}}" ></child2-app>
`;
}
```

and below is the `x-counter` elements inside need to declare (also you need to do the same at `child2-app` in order to two-way data binding between two child elements).

use the same property decleration at both `x-counter`  and `child2-app` elements:

```
static get properties() { 
        return { 
          myProperty: {  // my-property will be myProperty (camelCase syntaxt at child)
            notify:true //notify will alove up-side (from child to parent) data bind

          }
}}
```

So you have myProperty at both child element if you change myProperty element inside of a child this will be effected at other. But be aware, if you use as an `object` or `array` of this property. then you may need extra code for obserable changes at both element. example: `this.notifyPath('myProperty.name');`

EDIT: Below demo made with `lit-element`

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/rqprZd)

Comment: Thanks for providing the DEMO. I am trying to achieve the same with LitElement but unable to get data to child 2 from child 1.

Comment: Here there is a live example: I will update the same :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-example-ftlbz7?file=index.js

Comment: The code pen example is working from up (parent) to down (child). But not vice versa.  I am also learning :)

Comment: LitElement will allow one way binding and we need events to pass data upwards. Hence, I ended up using Events. Please look at the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fxhcp8